# Passing a variable to a Hive script file -- works with integer but not string

Tags: bash, shell, variables, hive

I need to pass a variable to an hql file in Hive using putty.  I've set up a test scenario.  Basically I want to select a row from a table where a value equals the variable.  It will work when the variable is an integer but not a string.

The hql file */home_dir_users/username/smb_bau/testy.hql* has this code in it:

```
drop table if exists tam_seg.tbl_ppp;
create table tam_seg.tbl_ppp as
select
    *
from 
    tam_seg.1_testy as b
where 
    b.column_a = ${hivevar:my_var};
```

*tam_seg.1_testy* looks like this:

```
column_a
A
B
C
D
ZZZ
123
```

I want to use PuTTY to pass the variable my_var to the hql file.  It works if I try 123 using this:

```
hive --hivevar my_var=123 -f /home_dir_users/username/smb_bau/testy.hql
```

But it doesn't work if I try to select one of the strings.  I have tried the below:

```
hive --hivevar my_var=ZZZ -f /home_dir_users/username/smb_bau/testy.hql

hive --hivevar my_var='ZZZ' -f /home_dir_users/username/smb_bau/testy.hql

my_var='ZZZ'
hive --hivevar my_var=$my_var -f /home_dir_users/username/smb_bau/testy.hql
```

But every time I get this error message:

```
*FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 9:14 Invalid table alias or column reference 'ZZZ': (possible column names are: column_a)*
```

I have also tried hiveconf, only one dash before it instead of two, not having hiveconf or hivevar before the variable in the code file.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is not a PuTTY question. It might be shell/bash/Linux question.

Comment: OK thanks.  I just mentioned PuTTY because that's what I am using and wanted to give as much information as possible. I'll remove the tag.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it looks like I have found the answer below through trial and error.  I am leaving the post here in case any other users new to Hive find this useful.

I put single quotes round the variable in the hql file so it looks like this:

```
select
    *
from 
    tam_seg.1_testy as b
where 
    b.column_a = '${hivevar:my_var}';
```

In a way this maybe seems obvious -- I would put single quotes round a string if I weren't using a variable.  I guess I had my VBA/SQL Server hat on where a variable would not have quotes round it even if it were a string e.g. = strMyVar or = @STR_MY_VAR (otherwise the result would literally be "${hivevar:my_var}" as a string).